# R: How can I make an offset label NOT show decimal places during an animation

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, data-visualization, gganimate

I am creating an animated chart from a dataset (using ggplot2, gganimate, ggrepel...) but I can't seem to get the label to round during the transition frames. Thus it makes a big long decimal number on the label. I can semi fix it by setting the label text to 'as.factor' or 'as.character', which will then only display the actual value of each point in the dataset, but ideally, I'd love to show it growing as it does with decimal places, but as whole numbers (or a single decimal place). I tried using various 'round' functions but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? :)

Code:

```
#################################################
# set libraries ----
library(fredr)
library(zoo)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gganimate)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(readxl)

################################################


# Import Data from XLS
my_data <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\total-world.xlsx")


a3 <- 

  # Decimal Places in Label when animated
  #  ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=Date,y=Cases,label = as.character(Cases) ))+
  ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=Date,y=Cases,label = Cases ))+
  geom_line()+
  view_follow()+

  geom_point(color="red", size = 4)+
  geom_line(size = 1, colour="#FFFFFF") +
  geom_area(color="white", fill="#093e58", alpha = 0.4)+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = round(Cases,1)),
                    segment.colour = "black",
                   fontface = 'bold',
                   box.padding = unit(0.5, "lines"),
                   point.padding = unit(1, "lines"),
                   segment.color = "Red"  ) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma_format())+
  transition_reveal(ind)+
  theme_gray()+
  
# Ugly, needs cleaning up...  
  theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "#ff9e2a", size = 15, face = "bold"))+
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "yellow", size = 15, face = "bold"))+
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(color = "green", size = 12, face = "bold"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#141e24", colour = "#141e24"))+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#203039", linetype = "dashed"))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "#203039", linetype = "dashed"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="white", size=14))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="white", size=14))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 5, 0, 0), "mm"), angle = 0)  )+
  
  
  labs(x="",y="Cases",
       title="Worldwide Covid-19 Cases Since the Start",
       subtitle="... stay safe out there ...",
       caption="Harry Royden McLaughlin - Source: ourworldindata.org \n Updated 04-11-2020")


animate(a3,end_pause=40, nframes=350,fps=12)
save_animation(last_animation(), file="C:\\Users\\xxx\\OneDrive\\Desktop")
```

Image:
[Decimal Places in Offset Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YylKG.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note - you'll get a better response if you can post a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug with `gganimate`, but I see the same thing in this example dataset and plot:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10,1,0.1), y=rnorm(10,1,0.1), t=1)
df2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10, 1, 0.12), y=rnorm(10, 1, 0.12), t=2)
df3 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10, 1, 0.15), y=rnorm(10, 1, 0.15), t=3)
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + xlim(0.5,1.5) + ylim(0.5,1.5) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=round(y,2)))
```

Here's the plot without animation:

[image]

This is what happens when you animate:

`p + transition_time(t)`

[image]

Here's a fix that works if you use `as.character(round(y,2))` for the `label` aesthetics.  I have to admit, I have no idea *why* this works, but it does:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + xlim(0.5,1.5) + ylim(0.5,1.5) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=as.character(round(y,2))))

p + transition_time(t)
```

[image]

One final point: you are calling your `label=` aesthetic *twice* in your plot, even though it's only used in `geom_text_repel`.  For aesthetics that are used throughout a plot.  It's generally good practice to only specify the aesthetics *once*, especially if they conflict with one another.  This is to make sure which aesthetic applied to your `geom` is the correct one.  I'm pretty sure it's not going to matter much for this case, but I would still recommend using declaring the `label=` aesthetic *either* just with `geom_text_repel` *or* with `ggplot`.